# How do I prevent swagger core from parsing Jackson annotation?

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, springdoc

I have a FormTemplateElement class which has a couple of subtypes. I want the schema generation to happen using solely the @Schema annotation. However Swagger is also parsing the Jackson annotations. Is there a way to prevent this?

I want to use the Jackson annotations for serialization and deserialization purpose, that's why I can't remove it.

I am using SpringDoc version **2.3.0** and jackson version **2.16.0**.

```
@Schema(
        discriminatorProperty = "formTemplateElementType",
        name = "FormTemplateElement",

        discriminatorMapping = {
                @DiscriminatorMapping(value = "ShortTextFormElement", schema = ShortTextFormElement.class),
                @DiscriminatorMapping(value = "LongTextFormElement", schema = LongTextFormElement.class),

        },
        subTypes = {
                ShortTextFormElement.class,
                LongTextFormElement.class,

        }
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "formTemplateElementType",
        visible = false
)
@JsonSubTypes(

        {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ShortTextFormElement.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LongTextFormElement.class),
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class FormTemplateElement {
    @NotEmpty
    UUID id;

    @NotEmpty
    FormTemplateElementType formTemplateElementType;

    @NotEmpty
    Boolean isRequired;

    @NotEmpty
    Boolean isHidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I wanted a solution for this is I was using the OAS3 for code generation.
Turns out polymorphism is difficult using @JsonSubtypes in my use case (I am using open-api cli generator for typescript fetch).
I kinda did a workaround where I am using @Schema annotation when I am generating the code using the cli and @JsonSubType for when I am actually running the spring boot backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).